# Extra-thick pasta machine for udon noodles?

Tags: pasta, noodles

I enjoy making udon noodles occasionally. But the main point of labor & annoyance is hand-cutting the noodles. I would really like a pasta-maker that is thick enough to cut out square udon noodles. Issue is that udon is a particualrly thick noodle so I don't think most simple hand-crank pasta maker's have this a thick enough cutting option.

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a [chitarra](https://www.bakedeco.com/detail.asp?id=36322&trng=fgle&kw=&cpn=17766200399&gclid=Cj0KCQjwl92XBhC7ARIsAHLl9anfzJtb41q42DvRglzRMYHeJZ8Eaiq6SU6d5zCQE421q3TkCxfNBywaAjj1EALw_wcB).  It is used to make a pasta typical to the Abruzzo region of Italy.  I use mine also for udon and ramen noodles.  It creates a rectangular shaped pasta...you can control the thickness with your roller, then cut on the chitarra.

Comment: wow interesting! thank you for the recommendation